# How to remove change password link from django admin site?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using active directory login authentication for my django web application. So there is no need of change password link in admin site.

I have searched lot of article, but I haven't found any thing to hide change password link. 
So what is the way of hiding change password link from admin?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to override admin template.

If [`user.has_usable_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_usable_password) returns `False`, then [Django will not display change password URL for that user](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L48).

`user.has_usable_password()`can be made to return `False` by calling `user.set_unusable_password()`.

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password):

> **`set_unusable_password()`**
>
> Marks the user as having no password set. This isn’t the same as having a blank string for a password. `check_password()` for this user will never return `True`. Doesn’t save the User object.
>
> You may need this if authentication for your application takes place against an existing external source such as an LDAP directory.
>
> **`has_usable_password()`**
>
> Returns `False` if `set_unusable_password()` has been called for this user.

[Source code for condition filter in Django base admin template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L48):

```
{% if user.has_usable_password %}
    <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% translate 'Change password' %}</a> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It does not work.  I overrode 'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend' and call 'user.set_unusable_password()' there. Therefore user 'has_usable_password()' returns False, but the password changing area is still there

Comment: This answer makes me wonder one more time if Django is really that bad or the person who gave the answer doesn't know what he's talking about