# Django Admin, how to hide change password?

Tags: django, authentication, ldap, django-admin, django-users

Some users of my Django application come from a LDAP server. These users must not be able to change their django-admin password. The best, if they don't even have one.

That's why I subclassed `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend` like this:

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CustomLDAPBackend(LDAPBackend)  

    def authenticate_ldap_user(self, ldap_user, password):
          
        user = ldap_user.authenticate(password)     
       
        print("BEFORE set_unusable_password(): ", user.has_usable_password())
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.save()

        print("AFTER set_unusable_password(): ", user.has_usable_password())

        return user
```

By `user.set_unusable_password()` I try to hide the password, because I read it in several places (here in SO as well as in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password)). But all I can achieve is having no password set:
[image]

Furthermore if I login multiple times, the result of `print("BEFORE set_unusable_password(): ", user.has_usable_password())` is always True, despite calling `user.set_unusable_password()` and saving the user. As if a new user object is getting created every time.

[This question does not solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62421279/how-to-remove-change-password-link-from-django-admin-site) because `user.set_unusable_password()` apparently does not hide the password-changing area.

**What am I missing? How can I hide the 'change password' area?**

Below is the LDAP-relevant part of the settings.py:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, LDAPGroupQuery,GroupOfNamesType,PosixGroupType


AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://localhost'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'secret'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('dc=example,dc=com',ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(uid=%(user)s)')
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('dc=example,dc=com',ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectClass=top)')
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = PosixGroupType(name_attr="cn")
AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS = True

    # Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "cn=enabled,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
        "first_name": "givenName",
        "last_name": "sn",
        "email": "mail",
        "username": "uid",
        "password": "userPassword",
}
AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {
        "home_directory": "homeDirectory"
}
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
        "is_active": "cn=active,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
        "is_staff": "cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
        "is_superuser": "cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
}
    
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
    
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
    
    # Keep ModelBackend around for per-user permissions and maybe a local
    # superuser.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (           
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'ldappro.backend_ldap.CustomLDAPBackend',       
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Overriding 'LDAPBackend' is indeed necessary, but not enough. It removes the 'Changes Password' marked with red only (top right corner):
[image]

The other 'Change Password' area (marked by blue, in the picture below) stays intact:

[image]

To get rid of the 'blue' area we need to override a template like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block field_sets %}
{% for fieldset in adminform %}

  {% if forloop.first and user.has_usable_password %}
    {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
  {% endif %}
 
  {% if not forloop.first %}
     {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This overriding template html needs to be called `change_form.html` and needs to be placed like below (red circle):

[image]